# Stability properties of scalar differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $C^\infty$. Suppose the following

(i) $f(0)=0$

(ii) there is a smallest $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $f^{(n)}(0)\neq0$

I want to examine the (Lyapunov) stability of the equilibrium at 0 for the differential equation $\dot{x}=f(x)$, in terms of $n$ and the sign of $f^{(n)}(0)$.

To do this I apply Taylor's theorem:

$\dot{x}=f(x)=\left(\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}+xh(x)\right)x^n$

with $h\in C^\infty$, so $Df(0)=0$ and hence it is a nonhyperbolic equibilibrium.

Any advice on how to get started and make a proper argumentation ?

(For reference this is Prop. 8.8 in *Stability and Stabilization: An Introduction
 By William J. Terrell*)

Comment: Well, what determines the stability of equilibria of flows at $\mathbb{R}$? There is a standard ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ and $x(t)$ either increases or decreases. How should trajectories behave with respect to that ordering in the neighbourhood of equilibrium if it is stable? How does that affect sign of vector field in the neighbourhood of equilibrium? How Taylor expansion helps you figure out the sign of $f(x)$ near the equilibrium?